# Cannot catch exception thrown by mixpanel.track

Tags: javascript, promise, mixpanel

I'm using mixpanel for tracking / analytics in my Ionic+Angular project. I want to catch the exception thrown by the `mixpanel.track`.

*Tried Methods?*

`mixpanel.track` returns `Promise`, on which I did tried using `catch` handler, but the issue I came to know is `mixpanel.track` is always(mostly?) resolving this Promise with the `OK` string immediately, and then after that when it actually sends the event back to sentry server, it throws the error around - Missing value for  and so on (the error here is not the concern, but the handling of it is).

```js
mixpanel.track('MyEventName', myEventProperties).then(data => {
   console.log('Even when there is error, mixpanel return OK in data, ', data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Not getting the mixpanel error in here as expected', err);
})
```

Is there any way / mixpanel API which I'm supposed to use in order to get these exceptions that I can handle more gracefully, or is this some sort of bug with the mixpanel that should be fixed by them?

Comment: You might use Angular but the error is not related to it. Please remove the angular tag from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a support engineer at Mixpanel and taking a look at this we do return a 200/OK if the track() payload is valid JSON but then fail if there is missing required data. Essentially you should try to not resolve the promise on the HTTP code but instead inspect the entire response. So don't manually resolve the promise before the rest of the code runs/response is returned. Also if you just want it to be treated as an error in the code and handle it in a catch block you can just raise an error if you see error in the response.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually resolve the promise"? The problem clearly appears be inside of the `mixpanel.track()` method

Comment: As an example, 
`a = () => {return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(); console.log("start");console.log(badvarname);console.log("end")})}` 

It will log start but not end which means it did error out. But also shows nothing in the error logs. If you're rolling your own promises you'd need to not resolve the promise before the rest of the code runs.

Comment: Sure, but I don't see any code in the question where the OP is rolling their own promise? It seems to be `mixpanel.track` that makes this mistake.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, our native track() method doesn't return a promise so I just assumed OP was rolling their own. Perhaps OP is using a 3rd party SDK. You are right that the issue is in the track() method returning 200 even on a failure. I synced with our team on this and they mentioned the reason for this is due to how the API was written 10+ years ago and now many older SDK versions rely on these error responses and we need to maintain backwards compatibility. They mentioned they would return 4xx if they rewrote today. Might add a param on that going forward as we do for import